# Istio virtual service subset not able to send request to specific pods

Tags: go, kubernetes, grpc, istio, istio-gateway

I have following scenario

- FastAPI (API Gateway)
- Users (gRPC service)

below is the deployment yaml

```html
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: users
  labels:
    app: users
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: users
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: users
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: users:v0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: svc
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: users
  labels:
    app: users
spec:
  selector:
    app: users
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9090

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi
  labels:
    app: fastapi
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: fastapi:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: web
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: USERS_SVC
              value: 'users:9090'
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fastapi
  labels:
    app: fastapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: fastapi
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      name: http
```

After this I tried to test virtual service and route to users service (version: v2) when https header is passed. below is the codes for virtual service and destination rules

```html
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: users-service-destination-rule
spec:
  host: users
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: users-virtual-service
spec:
  hosts:
    - users
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        x-user-testing:
          exact: tester
    route:
    - destination:
        host: users
        subset: v2
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: users
        subset: v1
```

Below is the deployment for user service (version v2)

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: users-v2
  labels:
    app: users
    version: v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: users
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: users
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: users:v0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: svc
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
```

When i passed header value, the request always goes to version v1.

```html
curl -H "x-user-testing: tester" localhost/users
```

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance